# map.putArray raises illegal data type null with array data

Tags: react-native

I am using this helper functions in my android that I got from [here](http://www.java2s.com/example/java-src/pkg/com/ibatimesheet/rnjsonutils-47574.html) basically to convert a ReadableMap object to a WritableMap object. For reasons I can't tell, it raises an error on a specific field:

```
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableArray;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableMap;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableMapKeySetIterator;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableNativeArray;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.WritableMap;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.WritableNativeMap;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.Arguments;
import java.util.Map;

public static WritableMap convertReadableMapToWriteableMap(ReadableMap readableMap) {
      
        WritableMap map = new WritableNativeMap();
        ReadableMapKeySetIterator iterator = readableMap.keySetIterator();
        while (iterator.hasNextKey()) {
            String key = iterator.nextKey();
            switch (readableMap.getType(key)) {
                case String:
                break;
                case Array:
                 logger.log(Level.INFO, "Key info= " + key + "=>" + readableMap.getArray(key));
                 //fails here    
                 map.putArray(key, readableMap.getArray(key));
                    break;
            }
        }
        return map;
    }
```

logging the column like this gives:

```
     Key info= collection => [{"checkedOut":false,"choice":[40226],"collectionGroupId":1,"maxLimit":10}]
```

and for some documents, it is just [] (empty array)

The exact error message I am getting is

```
       null

       Illegal type provided
```

is the field not an array? Looking at the putArray method i see:

```
 @Override
  public void putArray(@NonNull String key, @Nullable ReadableArray value) {
    Assertions.assertCondition(
        value == null || value instanceof WritableNativeArray, "Illegal type provided");
    putNativeArray(key, (WritableNativeArray) value);
  }
```

the object is not null nor WritableNativeArray.

Answer (score 0):

just in case anyone comes, ended up doing this (not sure if iti s the right way):

```
    map.merge(readableMap)
```